# React Native, react-native init AwesomeProject, react-native run-ios : Error

Tags: react-native

Try to install the Testing Application and got an error :
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
and :
$ react-native run-ios
**Erreur** :
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

ok, maybe try this:

```
react-native upgrade 
react-native run-ios
```

according to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11293
the last comment, this would fix it
but it's generally a buggy platform

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a cache issue with NPM. I cleared it up here by deleting my `node_modules` directory, and then following the steps here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5054#issuecomment-222624983

> $ `rm -rf node_modules`
>
> $ `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`
>
> $ `watchman watch-del-all`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5054#issuecomment-264718211